# Convert static imports to IIFE and dynamic import to AMD in rollup

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

Is it possible to convert static imports to IIFE and dynamic imports into AMD in a single file with Rollup?

```
// x.js
export default function () {
    console.log('x.js');
}

// y.js
export default function () {
    console.log('y.js');
}

// main.js
import x from './x.js';

x();

import('./y.js').then(y => y());
```

into

```
// bundle.js

function x () {
    console.log('x.js');
}

x();

require(['./y.js'], function (y) {
    y();
});
```

How can I achieve this?